# My Own layout in WooCommerce pages

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have static template made from PSD to HTML. Now I am implementing it in WordPress. It's not fully E-Commerce site. So I need to create single product page category page and shop page individually. I have already designed them in Bootstrap. Now I am having problem creating custom layout as my static site in HTML. is there any way so we can get product data in object and display in our theme by creating custom page template? or any other better option? Hooks and filters are so confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to theme a site. If you're using WooCommerce you can find their docs [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/).

Hooks and filters can be very confusing, but the more you use them and break stuff the more you'll grow comfortable with them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root folder of your WordPress theme and create a new folder called 'woocommerce'. Then create a file within that folder called 'single-product.php'. From there you'll navigate to the folder for the Woocommerce plugin and find the 'single-product.php' file. Copy the contents of that file and paste it into the new 'single-product.php' that you just created within your new 'woocommerce' folder in your theme.

To drill down further and create more custom templates you can navigate back to the Woocommerce plugin folder and find the 'single-product' folder. You can copy those files over to your 'woocommerce' folder within your theme and make adjustments to those as well. At the top of each Woocommerce file you'll see the recommended folder structure to have within your theme in order for those files to override the Woocommerce plugin templates. You can find more info here...

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/